# How to show pop up in video js after time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

How to show pop up after 30,60,90,120 ....e.t.c seconds in videojs .I need to use like set time interval like event listener that checks the use is actually seeing the video or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Create the instance of the video
  var myPlayer = videojs('my-video');
  // get the current time of the video
  // get

  myPlayer.on('play', function() {

    alert("You click on play event");
  });


  myPlayer.on('pause', function() {
    alert("You click on pause event");
  });

  myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
    var getcurrentTime = this.currentTime();
    console.log(this.currentTime());
  });


});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't really understand your question, and I think that @Rob Wood answer is pretty good if you know what to do with the code, but I'm going to do my best:

```js
var playing  = false;
var lastPopup = 0;

function showPopup() {
    alert("Popup test");
}

function checkPopup(time) {
    if (playing && time-lastPopup >= 30) {
        showPopup();
        lastPopup = time;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var myPlayer = videojs('my-video');
  myPlayer.on('play', function() {
    playing = true;
  });
  myPlayer.on('pause', function() {
    playing = false;
  });
  myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
    var currentTime = this.currentTime();
    checkPopup(currentTime);
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

With this, `showPopup()` will be called if two conditions met: the video is playing and the difference in seconds since the last popup (or start) is 30 or more.

Comment: The currenttime is not in seconds i need to work on seconds or minute bases

Comment: The current time **IS** in seconds as you can see in the official documentation: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#MethodscurrentTime Also, I beg to not downvote because of such things. Downvote is not for that.

Comment: Yes, those are seconds, in decimal type. 1.5 seconds are 1 second and a half. 1.25 seconds is one second and a quarter of a second. I don't get the problem here. If you check "when is more than 30 seconds", then it will trigger with `30.23412345`, for example. If you look closely, it increases by 1 integer each second, so `currentTime()` is seconds, altough it has also fractions of seconds, but that doesn't matter here because 31 is more than 30 the same as 30.5 is more than 30.

Comment: Having fractions of seconds in decimals don't means that is not in seconds, as you say. If I have half a dollar, I'm talking in dollars, altough I said that I have 0.5 dollars, and if I have half a million, I'm talking in millions, altough I said 0.5 millions, and if I say half a second, I'm talking in seconds too.

Answer (score 3):

Hey just change you script as below,

```
    myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
     var getcurrentTime = this.currentTime();
     var dc = getcurrentTime.toFixed(0);
     if(dc != 0 && ((dc%30).toFixed(1)) == 0.0){ // here you can mention your time interval
     myPlayer.pause();
     $("#hoverDemo").show();
     console.log(getcurrentTime+ "   ----  "+((dc%30)));
    }});
```

And add two div like below in html,

```
<div style="position: relative;width:640px;height: 360px">
<div id="user23Demo" style="height:360px;width:640px;">
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" style="height:200px;" width="360" height="200" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
    </video>
</div>
<div id="hoverDemo" style="height:50px;position: absolute;top: 10px;background:none;display:none;" align="center">
    <div align="center" style="color:white;background: red;max-width: 300px;min-height: 40px;">
        <div>You have seen this before.<br/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var poll = window.setInterval( function(){
  //popup code here
}, 30000 )
```

Or, adding to the timeupdate event...

```
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
  var getcurrentTime = this.currentTime();
  console.log(this.currentTime());

  //assuming getcurrentTime is in seconds...
  if( getcurrentTime  >= 30 && getcurrentTime  < 60 ) {
    //popup code here
  }

  //the rest should be self explanatory. If this function polls every 
  //second, you could simply use getcurrentTime == 30, etc...

});
```

Comment: I need to use time interval event when the video is playing